# don't works cancan ability for belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have some problem with using CanCan gem.

I have **ability.rb** file:

```
if user.nil?
  can :read, :all
elsif user.admin?
  can :manage, Publication
else
  can [:read, :create], Publication
  can [:update, :destroy], Publication, :user_id => user.id
end
```

And it is **publication.rb**:

```
  attr_accessible :content,:title

   belongs_to :user

   validates :user_id, presence: true

   validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

   validates :content, presence: true, length: { minimum: 240 }

   default_scope order: 'publications.created_at DESC'
```

And it is index.html.erb for publications:

```
    <% @publications.each do |publicate| %> 

    <h3><%= publicate.title %></h3>

        <% if can? :update, :destroy, Publication %>
          <%= link_to "Update", edit_publication_path(publicate) %>
          |<%= link_to " delete", publicate, method: :delete,
                              data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

And it's don't show `delete` and `Update` links, and if it's admin or logined user.
But if I change in `ability.rb`:

```
elsif user.admin?
can :manage, Publication
```

`Publication` to `User`, it's works, and I see links delete in user view:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to user.username, user %>
    <% if can? :destroy, user %>
      | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

And `user.admin can :manage, :all` , it's works too, and with users, and with publications. Why CanCan ignore Publication ability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read:

- [Checking Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities)
- https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/ability.rb#L56

and you should see why your conditional

```
can? :update, :destroy, Publication
```

is incorrect.  Your action is `:update` and your subject is `:destroy`, and your third argument, `Publication`, is basically being ignored.